# What could be causing my cyclic voltammograms to have a sloped scan?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, electrochemistry, cyclic-voltammetry

[image: ol]

I am running a CV (cyclic voltammogram) in a two compartment bulk electrolysis cell with pH 7 phosphate buffer (0.5 ion concentration) and a napheon membrane separating the two compartments. I'm using a platinum microelectrode with a Ag/AgCl psudo reference electrode and a large platinum flag counter electrode. Currently I am running the setup all in one side of the two compartment cell in order to isolate the distance issue. 
I took a first order derivative to show the slope of the line is rather constant.

[image]

This was a background taken, after degassing with both stirring and helium sparging, using a polished 25 micron platinum microelectrode. Any ideas what could be causing my background scan to be a literal diagonal line, rather than flat like a regular baseline?

Comment: Just related.  Labelling should be A • 10E7 if you want those values. I know that is normally wrong also in professional literature but it is so. Your background is perhaps a straight flat line depending on your requirements. It is matter of scale. It should rather pass by 0,0 but somehow obeys a linear relation with resistance related to the electrolytes in the cell.

Comment: @Alchimista Thanks for the insight, I'll change that. If it was due to electrolytes the slope of the line should remain constant though, correct? The slope of the line tends to change quite a bit between runs. I suppose it could be that I am generating new electrolytes between runs however.

Comment: Normally you should get basically noise without electrolyte and a straight line with it . All the rest depends on the actual set up (el. conc. and electrode size. Again, and as in general, what is crucial is what current do you expect later. If it is milliA or more, your line is a correct background, at least for the standard application of CV. And yes, you might have some electrochemistry going on, influencing the subsequent run. But you have tenths of microampere so it should not matter at all.